# Поиск разницы между датами

Tags: java

Должен написать многопоточную программу. Один из этапов разработки - поиск разницы во времени (разница может быть в годах, в месяцах или днях, в зав-ти от входных данных. Разница расчитывается с датой в прошлом и текущим временем).

Пробовал разные варианты, в виду недостатка опыта никак не могу подобрать решение, не знаю что использовать: LocalDate, Date, Calendar или иные варианты. На данный момент использую LocalDate, но путь как мне кажется не верен (не могу сравнить год и месяц).

Вопрос таков - какой тип данных я должен использовать для сохранения момента в прошлом (год, месяц, день) для последующего успешного сравнения (желательно путем обычного вычитания аля resultYear = firstYear - secondYear)?

```
package myDefaultPackage;

import java.time.*;

public class Timer extends Thread {
    public static final LocalDate DATE_OF_SESSION = LocalDate.of(2012, Month.DECEMBER, 12);
    public static LocalDate differenceOfTheTime;

    public void run() {
        LocalDate now;

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                sleep(500);
                now = LocalDate.now(); // получение текущей даты
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Сравниваем два объекта LocalDate, возвращаем их разницу в виде 
     * объекта LocalDate*/
    LocalDate compare(LocalDate dateOfSession, LocalDate compared) {
        LocalDate resultYear = dateOfSession - compared;
    }    
}
```

3 снизу cтрочка кода, где производится вычитание, выдает ошибку

> The operator `-` is undefined for the argument type(s)
>   java.time.LocalDate, java.time.LocalDate.

Что посоветуете использовать вместо LocalDate или как сравнить LocalDate (год и месяц)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
LocalDate last = LocalDate.of(2017, 6, 2);
LocalDate first = LocalDate.of(2005, 10, 8);
LocalDate resultDate = compare(last, first); //returns 0011-08-25

LocalDate compare(LocalDate dateOfSession, LocalDate compared)
{
    long resultDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(compared, dateOfSession);
    return LocalDate.of(0, 1, 1).plusDays(resultDays - 1);
}
```

Чтобы узнать разницу только в годах можно использовать методы

- `ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(first, last);` //returns 11
- `Period.between(first, last).getYears();`

Comment: enum resultDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(compared, dateOfSession); а не long

Comment: @АлексейФедотов что?

Comment: @АлексейФедотов Исправил ответ. [Этот сайт](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?d1=1&m1=6&y1=2017&type=sub&ay=2015&am=6&aw=&ad=1&rec=) неправильно считает, один месяц теряет.

Answer (score 0):

Недавно писал метод по этой теме/
Bспользуя класс Period для расчета разницы дат. Как вариант использовать untill.
Чтобы вернуть результат используем getYears, getMonths, getDays

```
LocalDate birthdayJava = LocalDate.of(1995, 05, 23);
    Period period = birthdayJava.until(LocalDate.now());
    return "С момента основания языка Java прошло: " + 
            period.getYears() + " years, " +
            period.getMonths() + " months, " +
            period.getDays() + " days";
}
```

Если надо добавить еще и разнице часов, минут, секунд, то пользуем класс Duration
Чтобы вернуть результат используем toHoursPart(), toMinutesPart(), toSecondsPart()

```
LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.of(2024, 01, 24, 0, 0);
    LocalDateTime fromJavaDate = LocalDateTime.of(1995, 05, 23, 0, 0);
    Period period = Period.between(fromJavaDate.toLocalDate(), today.toLocalDate());
    Duration duration = Duration.between(fromJavaDate.toLocalTime(), today.toLocalTime());

    return "С момента основания языка Java прошло: " + period.getYears() + " years " +
            period.getMonths() + " months " +
            period.getDays() + " days " +
            duration.toHoursPart() + " hours " +
            duration.toMinutesPart() + " minutes " +
            duration.toSecondsPart() + " seconds.";
```